# Synchronize multiple pthreads in a

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, pthreads, mutex

I'm discovering the pthread library (in C) and I'm having some trouble understanding well a few things.

First of all, I understand what a mutex is, I understand how it works, ok, I also understand the concept of the cond, but I can't manage to use it properly (I don't really get how to combine the mutex and the cond)

This is, in pseudo-code, what I want to do :

```
thread :
    loop :
        // do something
    end loop
end thread
```

So there is n threads, but each thread uses the same function. I want the inside of the loop to be executed in parallel by all the threads BUT each thread must be in the same iteration of the loop, meaning I don't care in what order the instructions inside the loop are executed between threads, but to start iteration 2 of a thread, all the other threads must have finished iteration 1 (etc).
So my question is : how do you do that ? Not particularly in a specific example, but theoretically.

**EDIT**

I manage to do it, I don't know if it's the proper way, but it's working :

```
global nbOfThreads
global nbOfIterations

thread :
    lock(mutex0)
    unlock(mutex0)
    loop :
        // Do something
        lock(mutex1)
        nbOfIterations++
        if (nbOfIterations == nbOfThread) :
            nbOfIterations = 0
            broadcast(cond)
            unlock(mutex1)
            continue
        end if

        wait(cond, mutex1)
        unlock(mutex1)
    end loop
end thread

main (n) :
    nbOfThreads = n
    nbOfIterations = 0
    lock(mutex0)
    do nbOfThreads times : create(thread) 
    unlock(mutex0)
end main
```

---

I obviously tried to understand myself, but there are some things I don't understand :

- The main one : WHY does a cond need to be pair with a mutex
- In some examples I saw something like this :

```
// thread A :
while (!condition)
    wait(&cond)

// thread B :
if (condition)
    signal(&cond)
```

well I really don't get the point of this while loop, I thought wait put the thread in pause until the condition is true (until the other thread send the signal). I mean I would get it if it was an if instead of a while.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

WHY does a cond need....   because the (!condition) you reference almost certainly depends upon some bits of the object not changing while you reference them.   Correspondingly, modifying the state of the object should be done in such a way as to appear atomic to any observer; thus a mutex.  While you could rely on too-clever-by-half hackery like atomic types, there is also the problem of ‘what if it was modified just after you checked it’ -- a race condition.    Thus the idiomatic lock(); while (!cond) { wait(); }.

The point of the while...   The signal+wait is not a handoff of control; after the signal, any number of things could happen to the object before a particular thread returns from wait.  Even though the condition might have been in the correct state, by the time thread A examines it, it may no longer be.   At the point of exiting the while loop, thread A knows: The condition is in the state I desire, and I have exclusive access to the object.

Answer (score 0):

Condition variables can have spurious wake-ups.  The condition might not actually be true when the wait function returns.

Depending on your task, a different synchronization primitive, such as a barrier (see `pthread_barrier_init`) or a semaphore (`sem_init`) might be easier to use.